# Thread dump for threads which are managed by executor framework

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have written following program. Basically  I am using `executor framework` to manage threads. I've also used a `BlockingQueue` and deliberately keeping it empty so that the thread remains in waiting state.

The below is the program:

```
package com.example.executors;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExecutorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = null;
        BlockingQueue<Integer> bq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor((Runnable run) -> {
            Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(run);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.setName("Worker-pool-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                    (thread, e) -> System.out.println("thread is --> " + thread + "exception is --> " + e));
            return t;
        });

        ScheduledFuture<?> f = scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println("Inside thread.. working");
            try {
                bq.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }, 2000, 30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        System.out.println("f.isDone() ---> " + f.isDone());
        Thread.sleep(100000000000L);
    }
}
```

Once the program runs, `main thread` remains in `TIMED_WAITING` state,  due to Thread.sleep(). In thread, which is managed by executor, i am making it to read an empty blocking queue, and this thread remain in `WAITING` state for ever. I wanted to see how does the `thread dump` looks in this scenario. I have captured it below:

```
"Worker-pool-main" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f7ef393d800 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition [0x000070000a3d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000007955f7110> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at com.example.cs.executors.CSExecutorUnderstanding.lambda$2(CSExecutorUnderstanding.java:34)
        at com.example.cs.executors.CSExecutorUnderstanding$$Lambda$2/1705736037.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As expected thread `Worker-pool-main` remains in `WAITING` state. My doubt is on the `thread dump`.

As it is `executor service` which manages the life-cycle of thread in `executor framework`, then  how this thread dump starts with `Thread.run()` method.

Shouldn't it be that first some portion of `executor` appearing and then `Thread.run()`

Basically , the doubt is:  when life-cycle is managed by `executor`, then how come `Thread.run()` is appearing first and up the stack  see portions of `executors`. Isn't `executors` starting these threads, so how they are appearing up in the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a new `Thread`, it will execute its `run` method on a completely new call stack. That is the entrypoint for the code in that `Thread`. It is completely decoupled from the thread that called `start`. The "parent" thread continues to run its own code on its own stack independently, and if either of the two threads crashes or completes it does not impact the other.

The only thing that shows up in a thread's stack frames is whatever gets called inside of `run`. You don't get to see who called `run` (the JVM did that). Unless of course, you confused `start` with `run` and called the `run` directly from your own code. Then there is no new thread involved at all.

Here, the thread is not created by your own code directly, but by the executor service. But that one does not do anything different, it also has to create threads by calling constructors and start them using `start`. The end result is the same.

What `run` usually does is delegate to a `Runnable` that has been set in its constructor. You see that here: The executor service has installed a `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker` instance. This one contains all the code to be run on the new thread and control its interactions with the executor.

That `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker` in turn will then call into its payload code, your application code, the tasks that have been submitted to the executor. In your case, that is `com.example.cs.executors.CSExecutorUnderstanding$$Lambda$2/1705736037`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I must admit, `thread dumps` isn't my expertise, however, at times i need to do. The way you have infer the information, it is difficult for me to do. Most of the times the kind of information which is present online is "just the basics and which's pretty obvious".  Any guidance how to improve the get "real" details.  How did you infer `com.example.cs.executors.CSExecutorUnderstanding$$Lambda$2/1705736037`. Any pointers on how to improve?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Every line in the stack trace corresponds to a method being called by another method (the one from the line under it). That code about CSExecutorUnderstanding is the code you submitted into the runnable. All the other classes mentioned come from JDK standard libraries.

Comment: You could look at the source for `ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624` and follow the calls from there.

Comment: I will go thru this, thanks for your answer. Just in case, if i have a follow up question, hope you would help. Best